# Access denied for user when php artisan migrate is running

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin, xampp

## Goal

Connect api (laravel 8) to database(phpMyAdmin, XAMPP)

## Error

When I run php artisan migrate I get this error:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (Connection: mysql, SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = draw_db and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:793
    789▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    790▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    791▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    792▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 793▕             throw new QueryException(
    794▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    795▕             );
    796▕         }
    797▕     }
```

## I checked:

- api folder is created in XAMPP htdocs folder.
- MySQL server is running
  [XAMPP Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsekt.png)
  [XAMPP Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwKa0.png)
- .env file database configuration:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=draw_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

- draw_db is created in phpmyadmin
- user in phpmyadmin with username root and no password with all privileges is created.
  By the way, perhaps it's worth mentioning that I am using **mac**

Comment: Can you login to phpMyAdmin using a `root` account which doesn't have a password ?
I mean by leaving the password field empty

Comment: I assume yes because a user with the name root and no password is in my User accounts list.

Comment: Let me explain the issue
MySQL uses UNIX socket-based authentication, and this seems to be the problem
Now if you logged in to phpMyAdmin you can see a (User accounts) tab, click it and then it will show you a list of users, look for (root) and press on it, then look for a (Change password button), click it and it will open a page for you. 
Now look for a (Password Hashing dropdown) and select (Native MySQL Authentication), and make sure you have selected the (no password) radio button, click go and you're done.
Now try to connect through Laravel, it should work fine.

Comment: However, please keep in mind that this approach might not be useful for a real production environment, but it should work for now
Let's see if someone can give a better solution

Comment: Thank you! It was well explained but unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I get same error